# Keep session beetween Azure B2C userflow and Keycloak SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've configured a SPA application with a **Azure B2C user flow** to sign in on my SSO (based on Keycloak) using OpenId. Then I've configured another application with a **Azure B2C custom policy** to sign in on the same SSO, but using SAML.
I have another application on AWS directly connected to KeyCloak with another client.

The user can authenticate on both my Azure B2C, then navigate to the KK app, where the user is already authenticated.

This is not happening in the other way. If the user authenticate on the KK app the session isn't shared with the AzureB2C apps and he has to do the login again. Likewise the session is not maintained between the two AzureB2C applications.

My custom policy is based on SocialAccounts of [MS Starter Pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack). And this is my UserFlow session configuration.
[image: User Flow Session configuration]

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't mix user flows and custom policies. Make everything a custom policy.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm creating a test enviroment for demostrate what can be done with Azure B2C federated identity